# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

i'm using Laravel 5.3

and i'm trying to select from the database the values for the lang files,

i created a file and named it global.php

and inside the file i tried to do this:

```
use App\Dictionary;

$language_id = 1;

$dictionary = array();
$lables     = Dictionary::where('language_id',$language_id)->get();
foreach($lables as $label):
    $dictionary[$label->label] = $label->value;
endforeach;

return $dictionary;
```

now, this is working but i want to select the rows using the short_name field and not the id of the language

i want it to be something like this:

```
$lables     = Dictionary::all()->language()->where('short_name', 'en')->get();
```

my database looks like this:

**Languages**

```
id
name // for example: English
short_name // for exmaple: en
```

**Dictionary**

```
id
key
value
language_id
```

and my models looks like this:

**Language Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Language extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $softDelete = true;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function dictionary()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dictionary');
    }
}
```

**Dictionary Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dictionary extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dictionary';

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Language');
    }

}
```

thank you for your help!

!!!**UPDATE**!!!

i added 1 more table called

**Labels**

```
id
label_name
```

and change the dictionary table to:

**Dictionary**

```
id
lable_id
value
language_id
```

how can i make this work so i can pull the label_name instead of the label_id

```
$lables = Dictionary::whereHas('language', function($query) {
    $short_name = basename(__DIR__);
    $query->where('short_name', $short_name);
})->pluck('value', 'label_id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel's `whereHas()` function as:

```
$lables = Dictionary::whereHas('language', function($query) {
    $query->where('short_name', 'en');
})->get();
```

**Update**

If you want to get rid of your `foreach()` then you can use Laravel's `pluck()` function as:

```
$lables = Dictionary::whereHas('language', function($query) {
    $query->where('short_name', 'en');
})->pluck('value', 'label')->toArray();
```

Comment: an update: i took your code and add this line so i dont need to change the file between the lang folders $lables = Dictionary::whereHas('language', function($query) {
    $short_name = basename(__DIR__);
    $query->where('short_name', $short_name);
})->pluck('value', 'label')->toArray();

Comment: can you look at my update and help me with that? @AmitGupta

Comment: This doesn't have straight forward answer, either you have use join or you have to do it by a foreach.

Comment: So I have to work with loops and remove the "toArray()"?

Comment: Yes, you have to remove `pluck()` and `toArray()` and use `get()` only.

Comment: Ok I will try, just add ->labels()->get() and loop the array?

Comment: add ->with('labels')->get()

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be something like:

```
$lables     = Dictionary::with('language')->where('short_name', 'en')->get();
```