# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent - select from 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

in addition to my last question [Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272889/laravel-5-3-eloquent-relationships)

i added a new table called Labels and of course create a new model for this table.

**Languages**

```
id
name
short_name
```

**Dictionary**

```
id
label_id
value
language_id
```

**Labels**

```
id
label_name
```

and i have this code:

```
$lables = Dictionary::whereHas('language', function($query) {
        $short_name = basename(__DIR__);
        $query->where('short_name', $short_name);
    })->pluck('value', 'label_id')->toArray();
```

I want to pull out the label_name field instead of the label_id

but I dont know how to make this join.

Comment: @TrevorHickey thank you for your spelling correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `join()` as

```
$lables = Dictionary::whereHas('language', function($query) {
                    $query->where('short_name', 'en');
                })
                ->join('labels', 'dictionary.label_id', '=', 'labels.id')
                ->pluck('dictionary.value', 'labels.label_name')
                ->toArray();
```

I am not 100% sure that will work, but you can give it a shot.